# Apply a function to each element of a matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix

I'm trying to apply a function to a Matrix but I don't know how to proceed.

Here's how I define my Matrix :

```
data Matrice a = Mat [[a]]

montre [] = "/"
montre (t:q) = "" ++ (Pp.printf "%5s" (show t)) ++ " " ++ (montre q)

instance (Show a) => Show (Matrice a) where
        show (Mat ([])) = ""
        show (Mat (t:q)) = "/" ++ (montre t) ++ "\n" ++ (show (Mat q))
```

Then, once my Matrix is defined I'd like to apply my function `z95` to each of the elements of the matrix.

Here's the signature of my `z95` function (which allows to convert a integer into this integer modulo 95)

```
z95 n = Z95(n %% 95)
z95 18 = 18%95
```

I tried to do a double `map` too access the elements of my Matrix but then I didn't figure out how to apply my `z95` function.

Thanks fo the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a `Functor` instance for your type, which is the usual way to map a function over the elements of a container.

```
instance Functor Matrice where
  fmap f (Mat xss) = Mat (map (map f) xss)
```

Now you can write

```
>> let m = Mat [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>> fmap (+3) m -- => Mat [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

or in your case

```
>> fmap z95 m
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ! it's exactly what i was trying to do :)

Comment: Or -XDeriveFunctor ? http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/deriving.html